# c++ optimizations for threshold images

Tags: c++

I'm writing custom threshold function. I have two implementations with strange result in performance.

```
const uchar *ptr;

const uchar *ptr0;
const uchar *ptr1;
const uchar *ptr2;
const uchar *ptr3;
const uchar *ptr4;
const uchar *ptr5;
const uchar *ptr6;
const uchar *ptr7;

uchar *ptrR;

for (int y = inset; y < height; y++) {
    // setup ptrs

    for (int x = inset; x < width; x++) {

        threshVal = *ptr + 8;

        *ptrR = (((*ptr0 - threshVal) >> 31) + 
                ((*ptr1 - threshVal) >> 31) + 
                ((*ptr2 - threshVal) >> 31) + 
                ((*ptr3 - threshVal) >> 31) + 
                ((*ptr4 - threshVal) >> 31) + 
                ((*ptr5 - threshVal) >> 31) + 
                ((*ptr6 - threshVal) >> 31) + 
                ((*ptr7 - threshVal) >> 31) + 8) * 20;
        // increase ptrs
    }
}
```

I rewrite this solution and get worse performance ([here is idea](http://aishack.in/tutorials/super-fast-thresholding-technique/))

```
static uchar threshValues[600];
static uchar *threshValuesOffset;

// call this once
memset(threshValues, 0, sizeof(uchar)*300);
memset(threshValues+300, 20, sizeof(uchar)*300);
threshValuesOffset = threshValues + 300;

for (int y = inset; y < height; y++) {
// setup ptrs

    for (int x = inset; x < width; x++) {

        threshVal = *ptr + 8;
        uchar *checkPtr = threshValuesOffset - threshVal;

        *ptrR = checkPtr[*ptr0] + 
                checkPtr[*ptr1] + 
                checkPtr[*ptr2] + 
                checkPtr[*ptr3] + 
                checkPtr[*ptr4] + 
                checkPtr[*ptr5] + 
                checkPtr[*ptr6] + 
                checkPtr[*ptr7];

        // increase ptrs
    }
}
```

The result is same, but performance worse to 25%. How I can get best performance with this problem?

Comment: I don't understand: you've declared a pointer to `uchar` and then you're dereferencing it. This shouldn't work properly. E.g. `*ptr0 + something` -> `*ptr0` is bad.

Comment: @ForceBru `*ptr = *ptr + 5` - add to ptr value 5. 
`ptr = ptr + 5` - move ptr pointer to 5'th position.

Comment: the reason the second version is slower is likely due to the extra level of indirection added by `checkPtr`. How to get best performance? No idea, it'd require lots of tinkering and would be probably be compiler dependent.

Comment: Well, allocating and manipulating memory is usually the performance bottleneck. I see that in the first example, you are just storing multiple pointers, and computing the value of the sliding window. In second one, you have allocated a 600 items array and than computing the sliding window of some part of it. It would be really great, to show the whole code of both examples. I hope I am not totally off-topic.

Comment: @TomášŠíma added more code

Comment: Could you try declaring `checkPtr` as `const`?